# Need to set a Sheet so code works, regardless of what sheet I am on

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I use this to split facebook url, it works fine IF I AM ON THE SHEET. I now will be running this from a userform and the sheet will no longer be visible or the active sheet. I have been trying to set the sheet so it will still work regardless of what sheet is active. However I am struggling to do so.

**Q)** Can someone please help me to set the worksheet "Facebook" ? *(so this work off the userform, regardless of what sheet is active)*

I have commented out my attempts, I have also tried using `With Sheet` but nothing seems to work for me

```
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim va, x, z
    'Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    'Dim va As Worksheet
       'Set va = wb.Sheets("Facebook")

    va = Range("A2", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    On Error GoTo skip:
    For i = 1 To UBound(va, 1)
    
    x = va(i, 1)
    If Right(x, 1) <> "/" Then x = x & "/"
    
    If InStr(x, "/posts/") Or InStr(x, "/about/") Then
        z = Split(x, "/")
        For j = LBound(z) To UBound(z)
            If z(j) = "posts" Or z(j) = "about" Then x = "https://www.facebook.com/" & z(j - 1) & "/about": 
       Exit For
          Next       
    End If
    
    If InStr(x, "/category/") Then
       z = Split(x, "/")
       For j = LBound(z) To UBound(z)
          If z(j) = "category" Then x = "https://www.facebook.com/" & z(j + 2) & "/about": 
       Exit For
          Next
    End If    
    
  va(i, 1) = x
 
Next

ws.Range("B2").Resize(UBound(va, 1), 1) = va

Exit Sub
skip:

MsgBox "Error number " & Err.Number & " : " & Err.Description & vbLf _
& "Problem at row :" & i + 1 & vbLf & va(i, 1)
'End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure **every** `Range`, `Cells`, `Rows` and `Columns` object is referenced with a workbook and worksheet like

```
va = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2", ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
```

Otherwise Excel cannot know which workbook and worksheet you mean and usually takes the active worksheet then (which might not be the worksheet you intended).

Here `With` blocks or variables might come handy to shorten it:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    va = .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
End With
```

or if you need to work with different worksheets you better use something like

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

va = ws.Range("A2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
```

Apply this technique to **all** your code and it will reliably work no matter which worksheet or workbook is active.

Comment: Super, I was adding `ws.` to the Rang, but NOT the Cells. Thats what the problem was. only took 4hr to sort it out. Thank for your help PEH, took you 2min

Comment: @Sharid yes **every** object that is located in a worksheet needs that reference to be reliable.